# Google Maps API for iOS myLocationEnabled not working

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to use the Google Maps API but am having trouble getting the user's location. The observed value never seems to change since observeValueForKeyPath is never called. 
Note: I am running Xcode6-Beta 5 and iOS8 beta (code is in Swift)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var camera:GMSCameraPosition? = nil
    mapView_ = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera);
    mapView_!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.fromRaw(0x01)!, context: nil);
    camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(mapView_!.myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 6);
    mapView_!.camera = camera;


    self.view = mapView_;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        mapView_!.myLocationEnabled = true;
        });

}
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) {
    if (keyPath == "myLocation" && object.isKindOfClass(GMSMapView)) {
        mapView_!.animateToCameraPosition(GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(mapView_!.myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 6));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of right now, Google Maps iOS SDK hasn't been updated to support iOS 8. So in order to use the location features, you're going to need to do the iOS 8 location authorization yourself.

You can do this by instantiating a `CLLocationManager` object and executing either `-requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `-requestAlwaysAuthorization` on that. You'll need to do this before setting `myLocationEnabled` to `YES`.

Be sure to also include the necessary keys in your `Info.plist` file. If you are wanting to use always authorization (as in the code example below), provide `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, or if you want when in use authorization, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. One of them is required, and if you don't provide it, location features won't work.

Here's an example in Obj-C. Sorry, I'm not up to date with all the Swift stuff yet. :)

```
// Rather than setting -myLocationEnabled to YES directly,
// call this method:

- (void)enableMyLocation
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
        [self requestLocationAuthorization];
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
        return; // we weren't allowed to show the user's location so don't enable
    else
        [self.view setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
}

// Ask the CLLocationManager for location authorization,
// and be sure to retain the manager somewhere on the class

- (void)requestLocationAuthorization
{
    _locationAuthorizationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationAuthorizationManager.delegate = self;

    [_locationAuthorizationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

// Handle the authorization callback. This is usually
// called on a background thread so go back to main.

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(enableMyLocation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];

        _locationAuthorizationManager.delegate = nil;
        _locationAuthorizationManager = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for this answer. What a maddening issue.

Comment: Yeah, `You'll need to requestWhenInUseAuthorization/requestAlwaysAuthorization **before** setting myLocationEnabled to YES`. Later, I put 'request..Authorization' right after the setting `myLocationEnabled = YES`, and I did not understand why it didn't work. Now I did. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for others facing the same issue in iOS swift:

Add Delegates:

```
GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

Variables:

```
    @IBOutlet var gmaps: GMSMapView?
    var firstLocationUpdate: Bool?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Function:

```
func startMaps() {

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let location: CLLocation = locationManager.location

        var target: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        var camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition(target: target, zoom: 6, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

        if let map = gmaps? {
            map.myLocationEnabled = true
            map.camera = camera
            map.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to add this in Info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <true/>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <true/>
```