# myLocationButton doesn't show on Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, cllocation

I have followed the steps in tutorials how to get user's location via Google Maps SDK. I used the tutorial provided by Google also by [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) but it's no use.
The location button doesn't even show.

Any help would be great, thanks.
Here's my code:

```
    class NearestDealerViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainMenuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nearestDealer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    let transitionDelegate = TransitionDelegate()
    var delegate: NearestDealerViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        println(mapView.myLocationEnabled)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
        println(mapView.myLocationEnabled)

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func backTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.dismissNearestDealerViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your map is not alloc when location is updated so nslog the mapView when didChangeAuthorizationStatus is called

Comment: @chiragshah My mapView is hooked up to my storyboard. And I also took your advice to nslog my mapView and it's not nil.

Comment: are you run this project in simulator then you try to change the location.

Comment: @chiragshahi can't understand your answer

Comment: Are you facing this issue while testing on Simulator or actual devices as well?

Comment: @KayAnn right now i'm only testing on simulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514074/google-maps-api-for-ios-mylocationenabled-not-working try this

Comment: on simulator you have to change your location by debug -> location  it enable your location button

Comment: I tried that already. It shows the location, thanks. But my concern is that will my code work on the actual device?

Comment: It should be fine, anyways Apple simulator has known issues when comes to my location & its button. Still when in doubt, test. Just side load it on a testing device and check it.

Answer (score 1):

You should put in the viewDidLoad() next line of code:

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```